# Why is 'Components' tree structure empty - RTC source control

Tags: rtc

In RTC source control when I expand the Team Area I have this view :

[image]

I can see the stream and its components. What decides if components should appear in Components folder ? As can be seen in screenshot this is currently empty. For other developers this is populated with components even though they cannot see the streams ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You see all components that *are visible to you*.

In other words, it depends on the **ownership** for each component.

- Any component owned by the project area or your Team Area would be displayed in the Component section.
- Any component owned by a single resource (a member of the RTC project area) or another Team Area (that you aren't part of) won't be displayed there.

The same would apply for the streams: check the owner of those streams to understand why a resource doesn't see it.

> Whats the point of hiding a stream if the components themselves are not hidden ?

The point (in hiding Stream even though it doesn't hide component) is **preventing users to deliver to that stream**: they can still work on the same set of component (visible because of the right ownership), but they can no longer see (and deliver to) a given Stream.

Comment: So hiding a stream does not automatically hide the components within a stream, the components have to hidden explicitly ? Whats the point of hiding a stream if the components themselves are not hidden ?

Comment: @user470184 the point (in hiding Stream even though it doesn't hide component) is **preventing users to deliver to that stream**: they can still work on the same set of component (visible because of the right ownership), but they can no longer see (and deliver to) a given Stream.